# NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate method not called when switching tab

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

My application has two tab bars. The first one presents a list of games added on view controller and save them on the core data database. Switching  on the second tab/view reads from the database and presents it inside a table view. I implemented the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegatewith` a fetch method. But whenever I add or insert an item to the context on the first tab and switch to second tab, FRC delegate methods are not getting called. But when i implement the same methods on the first tab I can see them being call when I made a change to the database.

```
    import UIKit
    import CoreData

    class AllWLeagueController : UITableViewController {

        var fetchRequestController : NSFetchedResultsController<GameMo>!
        var arrayOfGamesModel : [[GameMo]]? = []
        var gameMo: GameMo?
        var gamesMo: [GameMo] = []


        override func viewDidLoad() {
            validation(object: arrayOfGamesModel)

        }

        override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewWillAppear(animated)
            fetchRequest()
        }



        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


            return arrayOfGamesModel?.count ?? 0
        }
        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {



            if let weekL = arrayOfGamesModel?[indexPath.row] {
                if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "WL") as? AllWLeaguesTableViewCell {
                    let winCounts = WLManager.winCountMethod(from: weekL)
                    let lossCounts = WLManager.lossCountMethod(from:weekL)
                    cell.setOulet(win: winCounts, loss: lossCounts, rankName: rankString)

                    cellLayer(with: cell)
                    return cell
                }
            }

   }



  extension AllWLeagueController: NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

        func fetchRequest ()  {
            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<GameMo>(entityName: "Game")

            fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "win", ascending: true)]

            if let appDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate){
                let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

                // fetch result controller
                fetchRequestController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
                fetchRequestController.delegate = self

                do{
                    try fetchRequestController.performFetch()

                    if let fetchedObjects = fetchRequestController.fetchedObjects {
                        gamesMo = fetchedObjects


                        print("Fetech Request Activated")
                        print(gamesMo)
                    }
                }catch{
                    fatalError("Failed to fetch entities: \(error)")
                }
            }

        }


        func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
            print("TableView beginupdates")
            tableView.beginUpdates()
        }

        func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
            switch type {
            case .insert:
                if let newIndexPath = newIndexPath {
                    print("insert")
                    tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .fade)

                }
            case .delete:
                if let indexPath = indexPath {
                     print("delete")
                    tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
                }
            case .update:
                if let indexPath = indexPath {
                     print("update")
                    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

                }

            default:
                tableView.reloadData()
            }

            if let fetchedObjects = controller.fetchedObjects {
                gamesMo = fetchedObjects as! [GameMo]

            }
        }


        func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
            print("TableView endupdates")
            tableView.endUpdates()
        }
     }
```

Comment: You don't mention it in your question, but, just to double check, do you use the same context in both view controllers, and do you save your context? Perhaps if you publish the key parts of both controllers, we can be of more help.

Comment: Yes I use the same context(only have one ).

Comment: Can you show how and where the `AllWLeagueController` is created?

Comment: Done. I added the code from AllWLeagueController.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `fetchedResultsController` is updating `gamesMo`, but your `tableView` is looking at `arrayOfGamesModel`. But `arrayOfGamesModel` is never updated.

You can either change your `tableView` methods to look at `gamesMo`, or change your `fetchedResultsController` to update `arrayOfGamesModel`.

Comment: I changed the tableView methods to look at gamesMo instead of arrayOfGamesModel, FRC delegates  method are still not called when I insert a record to the context.  When I switch to second tab, the only method that gets called is fetchRequest. I can see the print("Fetech Request Activated") on the debugger.

Comment: I updated the controller(_:didChange:at:for:newIndexPath:)  method with the following code arrayOfGamesModel?.append(gamesMo), I can see that the tableView Begin Updates print statement only after adding a second item to the Database.It does not detect an insertion.

Comment: I understand. We would need to see the updated code, and the code for the first controller to see what is going on. As this takes us away from the current question (which has code showing a `UITableView` and `FRC` disconnect), I recommend framing your follow-up issue as a new question.

Comment: Done. Link is:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61233538/nsfetchedresultscontrollerdelegate-not-triggered-when-adding-first-item-to-db-tr